# Netbeans adding actions to output window

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I have a **netbeans platform application**,

The Output window consists of two tabs in which am able to embed one of the tab in to a separate component with the following reference,

http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqOWTabEmbedding

However, when i tried adding actions to it , the actions are not coming up in UI .

```
IOContainer ioc = IOContainer.create(new IOC());
InputOutput io = IOProvider.getDefault().getIO("test",  
         new Action[]{
            new OneAction(),
            new TwoAction(),
            new ThreeAction()},ioc);
```

am expecting the three actions to be shown in the newly created window.

Something like this,

[image]

But am getting only the white window.

However, if i don't embed the tab in to another component, the actions appear.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

IOC has empty implementation of IOContainer.Provider method

setToolbarActions(JComponent comp, Action[] toolbarActions)

you should add JToolbar in IOC and implement that method.